# I want to change icon of the button immediately

Tags: java, swing, dispatcher, event-dispatch-thread, thread-sleep

I am doing simple application, and have one problem.

I want to change icon of the button immediatly from code, but it works after method ends.

Here is my code.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

..
*some code*
..

Buttons[Id].setIcon(images.get(Id));

Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);


..
  *Some code*
..
 }
```

I click on the button, it calls this `ActionListener` method `actionPerformed`.

`Buttons[Id].setIcon(images.get(Id));`  should change the icon, but it changes after

```
Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);
```

How can I make it work immediatly?

Some dispatcher or what?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need the sleep part exactly?

Comment: maybe repaint() before sleep()?

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `javax.swing.Timer` instead of trying to sleep in the middle of a method. You're blocking the EDT from setting the icon.

```
Buttons[Id].setIcon(images.get(Id));
Timer timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do something
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```

See more at [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)